# I want to make search page where I want to display my searched data from database in a "div"?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to make search page(php) where I want to display my searched data from database in a "div"?I made a connection with database and searched for data in one phppage and created a div tag in another phppage.how can i display the searched data of one php page to be displayed in another php page's "div"

Search.php:

```
<?php 
include 'Searchdata.php';
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $searchkey= $_POST['search'];    
   $searchkey=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchkey); 
   $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM newentry WHERE Date LIKE '%$searchkey%'")or die("Could not search!");
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
   if(!($count == 0)) {    
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         $Date=$row['Date'];
         $Entry=$row['Entry'];
         echo'<div>'.$Date.'<br>'.$Entry.'</div>';
       }
    } else {echo "There was no search result!";} 
}?>
```

Searchdata.php:

```
<div>
<form action="Search.php" method="post">  
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: which page do you want to show the results?

Comment: in searchdata.php i kept "div" i want to display the result in that "div"

Comment: @yoyo your question is not clear. What is the url for search form and do you want to show the result on the same url or not? Do you want to include search form in the result page or not?

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: i want to show the results in searchdata.php where i gave a "div" for showing the results...in searchdata.php i gave "div"....in search.php i took the results and i want to display in another php page i.e in searchdata.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable to store the results in this case its $data. Move your include searchdata.php to the bottom of the code so it can reconize $data.
Then echo it on your html page.

html page

```
<div>
<form action="Searchdata.php" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"> 
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div><?php echo $data ?></div>
</div>
```

The PHP code.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$data = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$searchkey= $_POST['search'];   
$searchkey=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchkey); 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM newentry WHERE Date LIKE '%$searchkey%'")or die("Could not search!");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
if(!($count == 0)) {    
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
$Date=$row['Date'];
$Entry=$row['Entry'];
$data = '<div>'.$Date.'<br>'.$Entry.'</div>';
}
} else {
$data = "There was no search result!";}}
include 'Search.php';
?>
```

Comment: This shows the result in search.php but the question asked to show the result in searchdata.php

Comment: Yes..thank you...now it is coming in "div" .....but it is showing an error in searchdata.php that **Notice: Undefined variable: data**

Comment: move your include to the bottom of the php file.  The php has to run first then the include.

Comment: or the page included will not know that $data is.

Comment: I kept the include searchdata.php file in search.php at the bottom...but it is showing error in searchdata.php that data is undefined @Jonny

Comment: it works fine for me.  Make sure it is after the last curly brace but before the php closing tag. let me know what you find. check for your $ and for other typos